# Get Recent date using Javascript

Tags: javascript, date-time

I want to get the Max date in the column Date1. 
This is my code :

```
function RetrieveLog() {
    var getItemsUrl = "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('" + ListName +"')/items?$select= ID,Title,Date1,LastDD";

    var promise = $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + getItemsUrl,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            ArrayRetrieved = data.d.results;
            if (ArrayRetrieved.length > 0) {
                console.log(ArrayRetrieved);
                //LICENSES
                for (var i = 0; i < ArrayRetrieved.length; i++) {
                    var RecentYear = new Date(Math.max.apply(ArrayRetrieved[i].Date1)); // CAN YOU PLEASE CORRECT THIS FUNCTION FOR ME?
                    if (ArrayRetrieved[i].Date1 == RecentYear && ArrayRetrieved[i].Date1 != null && ArrayRetrieved[i].Date1 != "Invalid date") {                                                              
                        $("#LastDD").text(moment(ArrayRetrieved[i].LastDD).format('DD MMM YYYY'));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: is date1 column is of type date and time in list?

Comment: Also, do you want to retrieve all items from list or just single item with the max date in `Date1` field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `Date1` field is of type Date and Time, and you want to retrieve just single item with the maximum(latest) date in `Date1` field then try using below URL:

```
/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items?$select=Title&$orderby=Date1 desc&$top=1
```

Comment: Thank youuu very much